# MySQL command from file running from bash / results columns not alligned

Tags: command-line, bash, mysql

I've managed to run MySQL from bash command line , with queries from a file , like this :

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat pass.txt) < file1.sql
```

With the following result :

```
id      name    food    confirmed       signup_date     email   salary
1       John    Casserole       Y       2012-04-11      NULL    125.00
2       Tom     BBQ     Y       2012-04-18      NULL    50.00
3       Tina    Salad   Y       2012-04-10      NULL    200.25
4       Mike    Fish    N       2012-04-19      NULL    50.00
5       July    Cake    N       2012-04-29      NULL    300.00
```

All good ,the command works, but there is one problem : all the output columns are misalligned, as you can see. It's all messy. Usually when i have this kind of problem, I solve with "tr" command, and i tried it like this :

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat pass.txt) < file1.sql  | tr -s " "
```

But the result is the same, there is no change. Furthermore, i can't even use the "cut" command it. I tried :

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat pass.txt) < file1.sql  | cut -d " " -f2
```

And still the same output. Strange. Can anyone please help me ? How can run MySQL from bash with querries from a file, and have a nice alligned format as a result ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `column` command

```
column -t file
```

In your case this I think should work:

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat pass.txt) < file1.sql  | column -t
```

Output:

```
id  name  food       confirmed  signup_date  email  salary
1   John  Casserole  Y          2012-04-11   NULL   125.00
2   Tom   BBQ        Y          2012-04-18   NULL   50.00
3   Tina  Salad      Y          2012-04-10   NULL   200.25
4   Mike  Fish       N          2012-04-19   NULL   50.00
5   July  Cake       N          2012-04-29   NULL   300.00
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When used non-interactively (as in your case, where input is being read via standard input, from a file), the `mysql` client presents the results of queries in a tab-separated format:

From `man mysql`:

> ```
>    mysql is a simple SQL shell with input line editing capabilities. It
>    supports interactive and noninteractive use. When used interactively,
>    query results are presented in an ASCII-table format. When used
>    noninteractively (for example, as a filter), the result is presented in
>    tab-separated format. The output format can be changed using command
>    options.
> ```

Because the default separators are tab characters rather than spaces, your `cut` command should also have used the default `tab` delimiter:

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat pass.txt) < file1.sql  | cut -f2
```

If you want the same kind of pretty printing as in interactive mode, you can specify that by adding the `-t` or `--table` option:

```
$ mysql -t -u root -p mysql <<< 'select Host,User,Select_priv from user;'
Enter password: 
+-----------+------------------+-------------+
| Host      | User             | Select_priv |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+
| localhost | root             | Y           |
| localhost | mysql.session    | N           |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | N           |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | Y           |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Another good option to use. Thank you.